# ubuntu: launcher for the desktop?

Tags: ubuntu, desktop, launcher

Is it possible to create a launcher for the desktop in Ubuntu (Jaunty)?

Comment: I really like this question because the launcher essentially makes the desktop a rudimentary GUI. i.e. someone clicks something and then a script is run. I have created many custom launchers but never one to launch my own bash / shell script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should already be there by default, but here's how to add it:

Right-click on the panel, click "add to panel" option, select "Show Desktop", then click "Add".